# PHP array uses a lot more memory then it should

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to load a 16MB file, into an php array.
It ends up with about 63MB memory usage.

Loading it into a string, just consumes the 16MB, but the issue is, I need it inside of an array, to access it faster, afterwards.

The file consists of about 750k lines (routing table dump).
I proberly should load it into a MySQL database, issue there, not enough memory to run that thing, so I did choose rqlite: https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite. Since I also need the replication features.

I am not sure if a SQLite database is fast enough for that.

Does anyone got an Idea for that issue?
You can get the actual file here: http://data.caida.org/datasets/routing/routeviews-prefix2as/2018/07/routeviews-rv2-20180715-1400.pfx2as.gz

The code I used:

```
$data = file('routeviews-rv2-20180715-1400.pfx2as');
var_dump(memory_get_usage());
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's normal for PHP. The same data in an array will use a lot more memory.

Comment: You could try not reading the entire file into memory, just opening a file handle and seeking the specific data you need. That can still be quite fast. Can you be more specific about what you need this for? I think the solution kind of depends on that.

Comment: Yea, that cuts my memory usage a bit, is there any better alternative to an array which uses less memory? I should not be to slow. I need to resolve IP's to a Subnet quick.

Comment: Why not load the entire routing table into mysql and query as needed? Or perhaps redis or memcached? Are you using this with php cli or webserver?

Comment: Well, the servers got about 128MB up to 256MB total system memory, there works nothing except a SQLite database. Only option is to store that into a SQLite database which will for sure be to slow or put that into into memory for fast responses, but that consumes about 60MB memory per instance. But thanks for the suggestions, I will see how can I fix the problem.

Comment: modern servers have 1-2-4-8Gb of ram. why 64Mb is a problem?
256Mb total system memory - is it some kind of embed system? try to post the problem you are working on, that is not an issue itself - that is just your approach is not the best probably.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the Php [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) function. It allows reading data of fixed size. It can be used inside a loop to read sized blocks of data. It does not consume much memory and is suitable for reading large files.

If you want to sort the data, then you may want to use a database. You can read the data from the large file one line at a time using fread and then insert it to the database.

Comment: I ended up, using rqlite as database, and with a bit more memory it works fine now, but thanks for the ip